# How to check if user is already logged in via Spotify in Android Studio?

Tags: android, authentication, spotify

I'm developing a music app that has 'login with spotify' feature. I followed [this](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-authentication/) guide to achieve authorize users.

But i don't want to authorize users everytime they opened the app. That would be terrible user exprience. When we use twitter's SDK or Firebase Auth, there are some singletons to get current auth information. By getting that object we can know if user is already logged in or not when the app starts. Is there an equivalent class or mechanism to do so with Spotify's sdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Room database to save user data local. When user opens app check if user exists in database.

I guess you have some Splash/Loading/Welcome screen with your app logo when you start your app. You can save some information from user local and do auth there with that data (something like token or id).

Here is url for Room database:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Don't you do it as well. Auth states have to be come from network everytime.

Comment: Of course you wont just start app with local data. I guess you have some Splash/Loading/Welcome screen with your app logo when you start your app. You can save some information from user local and do auth there with that data (something like token or id). I didn't work with Spotify SDK before so i am not sure what information is needed to process login.